# Sort list but change the asterisk from being first to last

Tags: python, list, sorting

When sorting a list, I think Python considers `'*'` as to being "before" (is there a word for what is the order Python uses to sort?) letters and numbers, and I would like it to be the other way. I would like `'A*0'` to be after `'A0', 'AB', 'A1', ...` rather than being before them. How would one achieve that?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
list = ["A*0", "A0", "A1", "A*1", "AB", "*BC", "C"]
sorted(list)
Out[7]: ['*BC', 'A*0', 'A*1', 'A0', 'A1', 'AB', 'C']
```

I would want this behaviour:

```
list = ["A*0", "A0", "A1", "A*1", "AB", "*BC", "C"]
sorted(list)
Out[7]: ['A0', 'A1', 'AB', 'A*0', 'A*1', "C", "*BC"]
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add this example list and the corresponding output: `['ABC', 'AZC', '*BC', 'A*C', 'AB*']`? Currently, notarobot's answer sorts it as `['ABC', 'AB*', 'AZC', 'A*C', '*BC']`, which I believe is what you want, whereas @MechanicPig 's answer sorts it as `['ABC', 'AZC', '*BC', 'A*C', 'AB*']`, which I believe is not what you want.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows For a general explanation: in python (and in most programming languages), strings are compared character by character, and characters are compared using their numerical value. You can get the numerical value of a character using function `ord`. For instance, `ord('*') == 42; ord('A') == 65; ord('Z') == 90; ord('a') == 97; ord('z') == 122; ord('0') == 48; ord('9') == 57; ord('~') == 126`. This explains that `'*'` comes before the other characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a sorting key that replaces `*` by `~`

```py
lst = ["A*0", "A0", "A1", "A*1", "AB"]
# replace * by ~ when sorting (since ~ has the highest ascii value)
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.replace('*','~'))
# ['A0', 'A1', 'AB', 'A*0', 'A*1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the key to sort the existing sorting results again:

```
>>> lst = ["A*0", "A0", "A1", "A*1", "AB"]
>>> sorted(sorted(lst), key=lambda s: '*' in s)
['A0', 'A1', 'AB', 'A*0', 'A*1']
```

If you want to get the results at once, you can make the key function generate a tuple:

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda s: ('*' in s, s))
['A0', 'A1', 'AB', 'A*0', 'A*1']
```

This may be a little slower (because you need to build tuples), but I think it's easier to understand.

If you don't know enough about the key parameter, you can refer to: [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)